# ssh to a linux server not listing the PID from python using ps command

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I am trying to execute the below code in a linux server using 2 methods,

1. logging to the linux server manually, the running the script
2. From local (using the ssh command)

Please find the code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os

print os.getpid()

def proc_func():
    proc = Popen(['ps', '-eo', 'pid,lstart', '-a', '-f'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    for line in proc.stdout:
        print line.strip()

proc_func()
```

So When I am logging to the linux server manually and running the script its fine,

```
29706
PID                  STARTED
28811 Wed Oct  3 06:23:51 2018
13474 Wed Oct  3 06:30:24 2018
13484 Wed Oct  3 06:30:29 2018
13485 Wed Oct  3 06:30:29 2018
29706 Wed Oct  3 07:15:19 2018
29708 Wed Oct  3 07:15:19 2018
12030 Wed Oct  3 06:42:11 2018
21910 Wed Oct  3 06:58:40 2018
3445 Fri Jul 20 02:35:07 2018
3444 Fri Jul 20 02:35:07 2018
```

Here you can se the `PID`: `29706` is listed

But when I am trying to run the below command from local

```
ssh -T <user_id>@<linux_server_address> "python /path/to/the/code/in/linux/server/proc.py"
```

I am getting the below output:

```
13175
PID                  STARTED
28811 Wed Oct  3 06:23:51 2018
13474 Wed Oct  3 06:30:24 2018
13484 Wed Oct  3 06:30:29 2018
13485 Wed Oct  3 06:30:29 2018
12030 Wed Oct  3 06:42:11 2018
21910 Wed Oct  3 06:58:40 2018
3445 Fri Jul 20 02:35:07 2018
3444 Fri Jul 20 02:35:07 2018
```

Here you can se the `PID`: `13175` is not listed

I am not sure why it is happening.

Thanks
Sourajit

Comment: are you running this on remote hosts? you are not getting full output.

Comment: My linux server is remote. And I am running it from my mac(using the ssh command). I am not getting the pid generated by the python script using the `ps` command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not invoke `ps` with the `-x` flag.  The `-x` flag is required to list all processes, even those which do not share the terminal with the `ps` command invocation or do not have a terminal at all.